# Help! Need advice identifying the leads on this transformer

Tags: ac, transformer

[image]

Hello Guys. I need help identifying which pair of leads can be used for 110V. I tried continuity test with multimeter and got continuity on the following pairs (1&3) and (2&4).

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: The label on the transformer shows the appropriate connections. North American AC power is nominally 120 volts, but is often called 110 volts or 115 volts.

Comment: " I tried continuity test with multimeter and got..." that's right. The transformer primary will be two separate windings, one from pins 1-3 and the other from pins 2-4. With that information, you can draw a circuit diagram and see how linking the pins connects the two windings in series for 230V, and in parallel for 115V.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not as obvious as it might be, but the label tells you to put line voltage onto pins 1 and 4 whatever voltage you want to run from.

Then for use on 230V, you link pins 2 and 3 together, putting the windings in series without cancelling each other out.

Or for use on 115V, you link pins 1 and 2 together, and pins 3 and 4 together. That way means the 115V windings act in parallel, again without cancelling each other out.

Edit: This arrangement allows the use of a DPDT switch as a line voltage selector in a way that makes it safe to change while powered up, and there are plenty on the market suitably labelled (usually slide switches). Here's how you'd connect it up, it has a rather pleasing symmetry...

[image]

Comment: good catch, not at all obvious, I would have probably blown that one up!

Comment: @Finbarr. Thanks mate. I have both 110V and 220V output in my house but I'll be using only 110V for safety. I did like you said, linked 1&2 and 3&4 together. Then I connected my 9V AC transformer to the input i.e 1 and 4 pins. Checked the voltage with my multimeter at input its 8.8V and the output was 1.6~1.7V(Vin/Vout=5.17). and with 2&3 pin(220v setup) output was 0.7V. So, I guess I can safely connect to power outlet now.

Comment: @RahulSalin For safety I'd rather use 220V, because fot the very same power output you draw half the current needed for 110V supply.

Comment: @RahulSalin if this answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it using the green check under the up/down vote icon

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for mentioning it. I wasn't aware of that feature.

Comment: @RahulSalin it's considered courteous to those who post the answers.

Comment: Check the image: 2 and 3 are swapped between the question and answer.

Comment: Good spot, @OskarSkog - guess I'd have blown it up too! I've fixed the image.

Comment: @Crowley I'm currently using the using the 220V leads with 2&3 pins in series. Infact using 110v on the 220V setup still gives the 9V regulated out.I decided to go with 220V because in the past I blew a transformer absent mindedly plugging a 110V transformer in a 220V outlet and in a few sec it caught fire :-! .Learned my lesson!

Comment: @RahulSalin If it is just a transformer, it should give 220/9 ratio whatever input voltage is; for 110V it should output 4.5VAC. If you had transformer with 110/9 ratio its output for 220V would have been 18V. But I thought of the using 220V sockets instead of 110V. With 220V circuitry you have half the losses due to lower currents or you can use thinner (cheaper) wires.

Comment: @Crowley The primary reason I decided to use 220V is because its safe in case I accidently plug into a 110V outlet too  but vice versa its gonna be a disaster. The output from the transformer using the 220V leads with 2&3 pin shorted : 220V- 26V AC and 110V- 15.5V AC(again with 220V leads). This is well within the range for the regulator because the range of voltage that can be adjusted on the PSU is 7.8V 10.8V DC.

Answer (score 13):

I thought I'd provide a picture to illustrate Finbarr's description, as I think that may help:

[image]

Just to make things explicit.